# Write to stdout from a Qt Gui application on Windows

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5, stdout

I have a GUI Qt application and I would like to print version to stdout when I pass `--version` argument.

This work well on macOS, but on Windows, I can't print to stdout.

Here is a minimal example:

### stdout.pro

```
QT += core
QT += gui
QT += widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    w.show();

    // this will print on macOS but not Windows
    QTextStream(stdout) << QString("Hello world");

    return app.exec();
}
```

I've read that `CONFIG += console` must be used to print to stdout, but I don't want to see the terminal when I start my application. Is there a workaround for this?

The stdout must be printed only if the application is called from a terminal.

Comment: I think this is a problem with Windows itself, not necessarily with Qt. On Windows, you can either build a console application, which means that you have console output but also a terminal, or you can build a Win32 (GUI) application, which means that you have no terminal but also no console output. As a workaround, you can build a console application and call `::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);` from `Windows.h` in your main, which hides the terminal. Unfortunately, you can still see the terminal for a few milliseconds until it is hidden.

Comment: This solution may be appropriate. Is there a way to know if the application was started from the terminal or was double clicked?

Comment: You can probably use `GetConsoleProcessList` for this. It returns the number of processes associated with the current console. If the return value is 1, the application was started via double click. If the return value is greater than 1, the application was started via console.